# VueJS Router: Determine first page load to disable/change page transitions

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to change page transitions in my App.vue based on if its an inital page load (eg the user types test.com/something into his browser) or if the user uses a router link (the user is already on the page and clicks a router link to /something), but can't get it to work.

Is there a lifecycle-hook that is fired only once after inital page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Actually its quite easy:

$route.from.name is null on first page load, so you can determine the first page load like this in your App.vue:

```
export default {
 data() {
    return {
        firstLoad: undefined,
    }
 },
 watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
        this.firstLoad = from.name == null ? true : false
    },
 },
}
```